# Where are all the underground bunkers?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In Player Unknown battlegrounds there's a massive underground bunker in F4 filled with high grade loot. I know from a game where I joined a random squad that there are more underground bunkers as we ran across a small one as we were traversing the map.

I have not been able to find the smaller bunker again; how many underground bunkers are there and where are they located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [set of very useful maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lwYt.jpg) made by ShatterNL.

Check out this one:

<sup>(Click/tap on the image below to view the higher-resolution, original image.)</sup>
[image: ShatterNL's vehicle map]

You can see all the locations including the bunkers.

But be sure to check for map updates every month as the developers do sometimes change some things.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a [small guide](http://gameplay.tips/guides/476-playerunknowns-battlegrounds.html) that tells you all about where to find the main bunker and what the levels look like on the inside. You are right that it's in the coordinates of F and L.

> The bunker tunnel system is located at (F/L) and the entrances look
>   like a cross from above.
>
> There are four entrances: north, north west, west, south east.[image][image]

These are just a few of the pictures, the full guide includes more.

As far as I am aware (from my own experience and Google), there are not other major bunkers. I'm not sure what that squad told you.

Comment: We actually visited the other bunker, it was somewhere in the north and only consisted of one room, but it had some very decent loot. So there's at least 2 bunkers on the island, and I'm assuming there should be more.

Comment: Yeah I think there are some other small ones with single rooms scattered around, but this is the major one. I haven't found any mapping of the smaller ones. Most maps are about car spawns and location loot drop rates.

Answer (score 0):

I know of 3 besides the main one. 2 are very close to the firing range, one literally just outside by the road, and the other a bit further east from the range. There is a third to the west of the range probably about 3 or 4 times as far as the one to the east and it is a bit more north. I've been looking for a map of all of them but haven't found anything yet. The entrances look like thin yellow brackets on the map, like this [

Comment: Did you not see the accepted answer? It has a map of all of them.